# Terminology: Name of a permutation that consists of exactly a single cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, terminology

If $\pi$ is a permutation on $n$ elements, is there a name for $\pi$ if it consists of a single cycle? This isn't a cyclic permutation since I do not want any fixed points. So I suppose it would be a cyclic permutation that happens to be a derangement? Is there a name for these types of permutations?

Comment: An "$n$-cycle".

Comment: Is that the only name for one? I am searching for properties of these types of permutation online, but searching for "n-cycle" doesn't really provide anything. Even simply searching for "n-cycle permutation" on google doesn't yield any results about them.

Comment: @user340082710 You had better searching for "k-cycle" since Wikipedia and other people use that like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139721/what-are-k-cycles . Here JMoravitz means substitute your value of $n$ into that "n".

Comment: What are you wanting to know about them specifically?  There are $(n-1)!$ of them in $S_n$ and they satisfy the property that $\pi^k(x)\neq x$ for all $k\in \{1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ and all $x$...

Comment: Is what related to this other question I had: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979411/characterizing-the-number-of-inversions-in-a-permutation - I was not able to find anything myself, so I was wondering if they perhaps had a more common name.